# Is there any postConstruct/afterPropertiesSet for JAXB entity?

Tags: jaxb, initialization

Is there any postConstruct/afterPropertiesSet for JAXB entity
so that I can access initialized/parsed xml attributes and values to continue feather initialization?

Answer (score 2):

**Option #1 - [Unmarshaller Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html)**

You implement a `Unmarshaller.Listener` which providers a way to capture the events.  Then you specify an instance on the `Unmsrshaller` class before performing the `unmarshal` operation.

**Option #2 - [Event Methods on the Domain Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback)**

This method is called immediately after the object is created and before the unmarshalling of this object begins. The callback provides an opportunity to initialize JavaBean properties prior to unmarshalling.

```
    void beforeUnmarshal(Unmarshaller, Object parent);
```

This method is called after all the properties (except IDREF) are unmarshalled for this object, but before this object is set to the parent object.

```
    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller, Object parent);
```